# How can I make UIImageView non-clickable? Is it possible to do that?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, admob

I am trying to implement native ads in iOS app.

[image]

Small icon is clickable but it seems that it is against admob policy.

> Only the ad titles, URLs, CTA, and non-background image assets should
> be clickable.

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6240814?hl=en&ref_topic=7384666

How can I make it non-clickable? When I click small icon it redirects to Ad page but I don't want like this.

[image]

--

[image]

Comment: I don't think being able to click on the image view is bad. But if you wanted to prevent it, you would _check_ User Interaction Enabled in the _last_ screen shot. This would cause the image view to "swallow the tap".

Answer (score 2):

1. Disable User Interaction for the imageView in the storyboard

**OR**

2. Through coding

   imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

Comment: I disabled in the storyboard but not working. I will try in the code but I have a question. If it won't work with "false", why does google say "make it false" for Call to Action button? (because "Call to Action" button is clickable, google wants to make it clickable, interestingly they says "make it false").
https://i.imgur.com/sgmdmZf.png

There is an interesting thing, here.(I think, your 2nd solution won't work too)